# Android - ImageView fit in TableLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

How to make sure my `Imageview` fit in `TableLayout`? Mine can't be fit like this one.

[image]

Mine is like this

[image]

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/kelas_mengaji" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: as per your code i am getting your desired answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the ImageView

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```